# What subdirectories of a user's home directory does the user have full control over?

Tags: directory, home

What subdirectories can a user create in his or her home directory `~` with the intent (and reasonable expectation that the intent will be honored) that only that user have write priviledges? For example, maybe a new user, ignorant of [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), creates `~/.vim` and starts putting files there. Later the new user is sad, because the `vim` program wants to use that directory, too.

Comment: If "a new user, ignorant of `vim` ..." doesn't read `man vim`, they'll remain ignorant. In the "sad user" case, simply `mv .vim mystuff`, and let `vim` (or the `$USER`) reinitializate `.vim`.

Comment: Is there a Standard for `$HOME`? No. Read the individual `man` pages to see which files the program uses, and if they're configurable. See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.

Comment: What system are you running & what permissions. Ubuntu Home directories were created with 755 permissions but will be dropped to 750 with 21.04,  now to prevent new home directories from being readable by other users on the system. In Ubuntu you can run `ll` to see permissions. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: @waltinator Re "... man vim... " This implies that the new user would have to read every man page for every program that could possibly be installed. I'm looking for something less suboptimal.

Comment: In my $HOME I currently have 52 directories that have a `.` as the leading character. Most of these have been created by some application to store some information. `.config` and `.cache` are even more special in that many applications expect to be able to write to these directories. Some, such as `.ssh` or `.dbus` will be very hard to not have the user "be sad" when they will be used. Essentially, your options would be to read the man pages of the programs you use, check frequently to see if your "private" directories are being invaded by some applications, or start playing games...

Comment: (continued) with restrictive permissions and/or file advisories. FYI, expecting some weird circumstances that are a bit contrived, a user always has full control over the files and directories under his $HOME. `vim` will not touch `~/.vim` except in the case that the user explicitly invokes vim.

Comment: @doneal24 Re "...except in the case that the user explicitly invokes..." What I am gathering is 1) the user should know what programs are being invoked during a use of the user account (and home directory), 2) the user should know what directories/files each program touches, 3) Before using a program for the first time, the user should be prepared to move files, because the new program can arbitrarily demand control of a directory/file that the user was using for something else. #3 seems especially suboptimal to me.

Comment: @oldfred Re "Ubuntu... 755... 750": I don't think I am talking about permissions in the `chmod` sense. I suppose if _user_ invokes program _foo_, then _foo_ can maipulate any of _user_'s files according to the `chmod` permissions. But a "nice" program would alter only a small, well-defined set of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None.

The system administrator can always override any restrictions.

Comment: _Touche_! I am trying to get at something else, but I think I need to ask a different question. The responses should help with that.

Comment: With the possible exception of having files on an NFS share with Kerberos security in place. Other network file systems can also block root access and might be able to block access unless the user's password is entered. CIFS shares come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

By default, other unprivileged users cannot create subdirectories in your home directory. If they were able to do so that would be a huge security hole.

However, as said by @Jörg, the privileged user (root) has full read and write access to all users' directories.

Note that programs such as `vim` or `ssh` can (and will) create subdirs or files in your home directory.  These subdirs and files usually start with a dot to indicate they store system configuration data.